# How to add footnote in the YAML block of a Quarto document?

Tags: r, yaml, quarto

I am trying to add a footnote to `affiliation` in the YAML block, but got a mixed result:

[image: Output]

1. It successfully shows the footnote in both the behavior and format.
2. But in the Footnote section below, it shows 3 repetitive footnotes, rather than one unique note.
   *(I have tested with different words and combinations, they always result in 3 footnotes, so the length of text should not be the reason caused this)*
3. In addition, it starts from 3, instead of 1.

I am just wondering how to display the footnote correctly?

Here is my full YAML block:

```
---
title: "How to add footnote in the YAML block?"
subtitle: "A Quesiton for Stackoverflow<br>"
date: today
published-title: "LAST UPDATED"
affiliation-title: "TEAMS"

author:
  - name: "Yang Hu"
    affiliation: 
        name: \- ^[Retired]

execute: 
  freeze: auto

toc: true
toc-title: "Contents"
toc-location: "left"
toc-depth: 4

format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    self-contained: true
    smooth-scroll: true
    link-external-newwindow: true
    code-overflow: scroll
    code-fold: show
    code-line-numbers: true
    code-tools: true
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 268px
      body-width: 800px
      margin-width: 320px
      
number-sections: false
code-annotations: hover
reference-location: document
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on my end. The minimal YAML header to reproduce seems to be:

```
---
title: "How to add a footnote in the YAML block?"
subtitle: "A Question for Stackoverflow"
author: "Yang Hu ^[Retired]"
format: html
---
```

After changing the format to `native` we can see that pandoc renders the author information and the footnote three times in the meta data, for `author`, `authors` and `author-by`.

We can write a little pandoc filter in Lua that removes the first two notes and only accepts the third note and notes after that.

`fix_meta_notes.lua`:

```
notes = 0

return {
  {
    Note = function (el)
      notes = notes + 1
      if notes >= 3 then
        return el
      else
        return ""
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

And this is what the YAML header with another note in the body would look like.

```
---
title: "How to add footnote in the YAML block?"
subtitle: "A Quesiton for Stackoverflow"
author: "Yang Hu ^[Retired]"
format:
  html: 
    filters: 
      - fix_meta_notes.lua
---

Something ^[Another Note]
```

Comment: Wow, this approach is definitely beyond me - thank you so much!